# How to just trim left or right in PetitParserDart

Tags: dart, trim, petitparser

There is a `trim()` method which will create a parser to trim a string on both side.

How to create one which just trim the left or right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following helpers create parsers that trim in all possible ways:

```
Parser trim(Parser parser, [Parser trimmer]) {
  if (trimmer == null) trimmer = whitespace();
  return trimmer.star().seq(parser).seq(trimmer.star()).pick(1);
}

Parser trimRight(Parser parser, [Parser trimmer]) {
  if (trimmer == null) trimmer = whitespace();
  return parser.seq(trimmer.star()).pick(0);
}

Parser trimLeft(Parser parser, [Parser trimmer]) {
  if (trimmer == null) trimmer = whitespace();
  return trimmer.star().seq(parser).pick(1);
}
```

The above function `trim` results in an equivalent parser to the built-in function `Parser.trim`.